# Неправильно работает QSqlQuery

Tags: база-данных, qt, postgresql

Рассмотрим несколько примеров работы с QSqlQuery. По моему мнению, все эти примеры должны работать одинаково. Работу примеров я рассматривал с помощью отладчика и Wireshark (смотрел, какие запросы реально идут к серверу PostgreSQL).

**Пример 1.**

*Здесь и далее часть кода подключения к БД опущена из экономии места*

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.open();
QSqlQuery q(db);
q.prepare("SELECT * FROM get_person(:user_name)");
q.bindValue(":user_name", "gagarin");
q.exec();
```

Этот пример работает так, как и ожидается. При выполнении метода `prepare` запросу присваивается текстовый идентификатор, и на сервер отправляется этот идентификатор и параметрический запрос. При выполнении метода `exec` на сервер отправляется идентификатор запроса и набор параметров. Сервер возвращает результат запроса.

**Пример 2.**

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
QSqlQuery q(db);
db.open();
q.prepare("SELECT * FROM get_person(:user_name)");
q.bindValue(":user_name", "gagarin");
q.exec();
```

Этот пример работает неправильно. Несмотря на то, что в конструктор QSqlQuery передаётся ещё не открытая база данных по значению (то есть срабатывает конструктор копирования), согласно документации, реальные параметры запроса хранятся в глобальном пространстве, и код обращается к ним по имени соединения. То есть не должно быть разницы, открываю я соединение до конструктора запроса или после него. Но посмотрим, что в этом случае получается. При вызове метода `prepare` не происходит ничего. При вызове метода `exec` на сервер уходит вот такая чушь:

```
SELECT * FROM get_person('gagarin'
```

Соответственно, сервер не может вернуть данные. Если бы запрос был непараметрический, например, запрос представления, то он бы сработал, но отправился бы на сервер при вызове `exec`, а не `prepare`. Это неправильно.

**Пример 3**

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
QSqlQuery q(db);
db.open();
q.prepare("SELECT * FROM get_person(:user_name)");
q.addBindValue("gagarin");
q.exec();
```

В этом случае вызов метода `prepare` опять же не приводит ни к каким действиям. А вот при вызове `exec` запрос строится без ошибок. Вот что ушло на сервер:

```
SELECT * FROM get_person('gagarin')
```

Сервер успешно возвращает результат запроса. И всё же это неправильное поведение, так как сам текст запроса должен был отправиться при вызове `prepare`, а при вызове `exec` - только идентификатор запроса и набор параметров.

**Что же это, баг, фича? Были ли у вас такие проблемы?**

*Используемая версия Qt - 5.3*

*Дополнено: Переход на версию Qt 5.6.1 не решил проблему.*

*Дополнено: во всех трёх примерах метод `prepare` вернул истину.*

[Добавил перевод вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723488/qsqlquery-works-wrong)

Comment: Проверил на Windows 8.1 x64, VS2013, Qt 5.3, PostgreSQL 9.2.3 x32 - все примеры, кроме второго работают нормально. Причем если во втором примере использовать не функцию, а просто SELECT WHERE с параметром - то работает нормально.

Comment: @AlexanderMedvidov, думаю, что в вашем случае примеры лишь выглядят так, будто работают правильно, т.к. текст запроса должен отправляться на сервер при выполнении метода prepare. Таким образом, мы видим две не связанные друг с другом ошибки: 1) запрос отправляется на сервер в функции exec при создании QSqlQuery до открытия соединения; 2) метод prepare неверно обрабатывает скобки в запросах, т.к. запрос без скобок выполнился нормально.